# How do I not render the toggle button when on a specific page?

Tags: reactjs

I don't want to render the 'navbar-toggler' button when I am on a specific page for example on a login page. I know I would have to use conditional rendering but how do I get the path as it is on another file.

> App.js

```
const App = props => {
let routes = (
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
    </Switch>
```

}

> Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = props => {
            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"/>
            </button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways is you can use Location to match the path and hide it. import `useLocation` from `react-router-dom`. You can add more page paths as you go.

```
const location = useLocation();   
{!location.pathname.includes("signin") && <Button>...</Button>}
```